# How to Include multiple plots in a single Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

For example if I had one function `Sin[x]/x=c` and a second one `Cos[x]/x=c` than `Manipulate` for each separately is:
For the first one

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x]/x-c , {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {c, 0, 2}]
```

and for the second one

```
Manipulate[Plot[Cos[x]/x-c , {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {c, 0, 2}].
```

But as you can see, the parameter c is the same in both cases. Therefore I would like those to functions to be in the same `Manipulate` BUT not on the same plot. I want them to be side by side or maybe one above the other - not important just as long as they don't overlap each other. Is that possible? Can this be done?

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Plot[Cos[x]/x - c, {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
    Plot[Sin[x]/x - c, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]}}], {c, 0, 2}]`?

Comment: Just looking at this question... how exactly is this off-topic for this site (???)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

```
Manipulate[
 Row[
  Plot[#[x]/x - c , {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-1, 1}}] & /@ {Sin, Cos}], {c, 0, 2}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Exactly like this! This is Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: How can I rename the parameter c? Actually, I don't want to rename it, it just want it in the output to write "Frequency".. I tried {{c, 1,"Freq"}, cellnumber, 1}  and it doesn't work at all. (cellnumber=25)

Comment: @skrat, You should change the value of option `PlotRange`. So like this `Manipulate[ Row[Plot[#[x]/x - c, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {-30, 10}}] & /@ {Sin, Cos}], {{c, 1, "Freq"}, 25, 1}]`